# iOS app crashing when submitting textfield in Arabic

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app is an e-commerce app. When I add a new product from iOS if I fill the description field in English it post the product successfully, but when I try Arabic and after clicking the submit button it crashes with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

removeQuotesFromHTML breaks when called

```
    (NSString *)removeQuotesFromHTML:(NSString *)html {
  
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"“" withString:@"&quot;"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"”" withString:@"&quot;"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r"  withString:@"\\r"];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"  withString:@"\\n"];
        return html;
}
```

the first breakpoint happens in the following code, at delegat.postProductArray i think it actually break when getHTML is called

```
(void) SaveProductBtnTapped
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
  [delegate.postProductArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:[self getHTML]];
      NSString * message=@"";
    if([delegate.addProductPhotos count]==0){
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"uploadimage"];
    }else if([[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@""] || [[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"what_are_you_selling"]]){
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"titlecannotblank"];
    }else if([[self getText] isEqualToString:@""]){
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"descriptioncannotblank"];
    }else if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:4]] isEqualToString:@""]&&!freeProduct){
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"pricecannotblank"];
    }
    else if([[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:4]integerValue]==0&&!freeProduct)
    {
        //Entrez le prix valide
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"entervalidprice"];
    }
    else if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:5]] isEqualToString:@""]){
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"currencycodenotselected"];
    }else if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:0]] isEqualToString:@""]){
        message=[delegate.languageDict objectForKey:@"select_category"];
    }else if([[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:7] isEqualToString:@""]||[[delegate.postProductArray objectAtIndex:7]isEqualToString:@"North Atlantic Ocean"]){
        message[delegate.languageDictobjectForKey:@"locationnotselected"];
```

and the following breaks when calling removeQuotesFromHTML

```
(NSString *)getHTML
{
    NSString *html = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"zss_editor.getHTML();"];
    //NSString *html = [editorView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"zss_editor.getHTML();"];
    html = [self removeQuotesFromHTML:html];
    html = [self tidyHTML:html];
    return html;
}
```

Comment: The message in console: `Message sent to a deallocated instance` is important. Your object was released too soon. Wha's `getHTML`?

Comment: this is my getHTML method https://i.ibb.co/zh2p65Z/Screen-Shot-1442-10-20-at-11-23-07-AM.png

Comment: @Larme I also got malloc message by using  "po malloc(0x600199b34fd0)"  with code of the message you talked about, I got this  malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=105559989899264, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)

Comment: lines 5286 and 5287 replace the `"` you just added the line before. And HTML is a Zombie (always wanted to comment this), is the object set weak instead of used with strong ownership? But at first i would exchange lines 2663 and 2662 and see what happens. Make sure in line 4489 that your code has an result and how to handle if the string result is **nil**.

Comment: Do you post codes as screenshot. Paste your related codes in your question and format it well please.

Comment: @Raptor I fixed it and added the code...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
NSString * newHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", html];

newHTML = [newHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
//...... all replaces

return newHTML;
```

Comment: How does this relate to OP's question?

Comment: I tried but this @""" cause an error the double quotes has to be escaped like you did in this one withString:@"\"".... I tried with escaping the double but it still crashes when I fill the description in Arabic, but when I fill in English it works, also I recently added wkwebview as apple requires, could it cause something like this? also how to catch the zombie object? I tried with instruments but the app crashes and I get nothing...