# iOS app crashing when submitting long text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app is an e-commerce app. When I add a new product from iOS if I fill the description field in English it post the product successfully, but when I try Arabic and after clicking the submit button it crashes with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) you can see the details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784520/ios-app-crashing-when-submitting-textfield-in-arabic?noredirect=1#comment119872409_67784520)...

I found the problem it's this method, so the resultString doesn't accept long text now I want to make it accept long text, when I checked by using po malloc() I got this error

AddressSanitizer: requested allocation size 0x6110003a6500 (0x6110003a7500 after adjustments for alignment, red zones etc.) exceeds maximum supported size of 0x10000000000 (thread T0)

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script {
    
    __block NSString *resultString = nil;
    __block BOOL finished = NO;
    

    [editorView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            if (result != nil) {

                resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        finished = YES;
    }];

    while (!finished)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
        return resultString;
}
```

Comment: Wait, you're converting an async call into a sync call? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround the problem by retaining the resultString as shown in the code below, I don't know if it is a good practice, but it is working for now.

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script {

__block NSString *resultString = nil;
__block BOOL finished = NO;


[editorView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    
    if (error == nil) {
        if (result != nil) {

            resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
            [resultString retain];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@ll", error.localizedDescription);
    }
        finished = YES;
    
     
}];


while (!finished)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}

return resultString;
```